# Division on remainders

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm looking at G. Chrystal's Algebra book, Vol. 1. One question asks:

"If the remainder on dividing $N$ by $a$ be $R$, and the quotient $P$, and we divide $P$ by $b$ and find a remainder $S$, show that the remainder on dividing $N$ by $ab$ will be $aS+R$."

I know that from this, we have $ N=aP+R$, but I'm having trouble on how to work with the remainder.

Comment: We also have $P=bq+S$ for some $q$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  From the first statement, as you said, $$N=aP+R$$
From the second statement, applying Euclid's lemma again, we have:
$$P=Tb+S$$
For some whole number $T$, and $S<b$. Now substitute this equation in the first.

Comment: @Caleb After this, you must show that $aS+R<ab$

Comment: @ajotatxe If $Qab<N$, then $aS+R<ab$ because it is a remainder of $\frac{N}{ab}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{N}{a}=P+\frac{R}{a}$$

$$\frac{N}{ab}=\frac{P}{b}+\frac{R}{ab}$$

$$\frac{N}{ab}=Q+\frac{S}{b}+\frac{R}{ab} = Q+\frac{aS+R}{ab}$$